# Skip items for a period of time after backpressure buffer overflows

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

My use case is showing notifications in an Android app using a Snackbar. I can only show one notification at a time so I am using onBackpressureBuffer  and only requesting the next item when the Snackbar is dismissed. This works well, but I want there to be a cool-off period if the buffer ever overflows so that we don't just have a constant stream of notifications. In other words, when the buffer overflows, skip new emissions for a certain period of time.

So far I have something like this

```
observable
    .onBackpressureBuffer(
        bufferSize,
        () -> { /* start cool-off time here */ },
        BackpressureOverflow.ON_OVERFLOW_DROP_LATEST)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber() {
        void onStart() {
            request(1);
        }

        void onNext(item) {
            snackBar = createSnackbar(item);
            snackBar.setCallback((sb, event) -> { request(1) }
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
```

In the onOverflow action of OperatorOnBackpressureBuffer, I want to somehow start the cool-off period.

It seems like I want some combination of backpressure buffer and throttleWithTimeout or skip. I was hoping I could achieve this with a new BackpressureOverflow.Strategy but that doesn't seem to provide much flexibility. Is there an easy way to combine these in the way that I want?

Thanks!